# More than 99% of groups of order less than 2000 are of order 1024?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, groups-enumeration

In [Algebra: Chapter 0](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~jarekw/pdf/Algebra0TextboookAluffi.pdf), the author made a remark (footnote on page 82), saying that more than 99% of groups of order less than 2000 are of order 1024.

Is this for real? How can one deduce this result? Is there a nice way or do we just check all finite groups up to isomorphism?

Thanks!

Comment: There are $49487365422$ of order 1024

Comment: This was a result of Besche, Eick and O'Brien. Note that O'Brien $\Rightarrow$ computer usage. See [mathscinet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1935567). Basically, the paper is a survey discussing methods and algorithms used to construct (small) groups.

Comment: No doubt this about _isomorphism classes_ of groups.

Comment: Is there a rough estimate (say one significant digit) of the number of groups of order 2048?

Comment: @yatima2975: From [this article](http://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf) : "gnu(2048) is still not
precisely known, but it strictly exceeds 1774274116992170, which is the exact number
of groups of order 2048 that have exponent-2 class 2, and can confidently be expected
to agree with that number in its first 3 digits."

Comment: Is there a chart (or database to build one) to visualize the distribution of group orders less than $n$ for individual $n$ up to  ~2000?

Comment: @alancalvitti: Try this one http://oeis.org/A000001/b000001.txt

Comment: I am shocked why nobody on stackexchange has bothered to correct the ludicrous  wording of this question. This question is about _number of groups of order..._ and not _groups_ themselves. A group of order less than 2000 cannot _be_ a group of order 1024, of course, in case any reader is wondering, like I did, for a long time.

Comment: @NUnnikrishnan What? the question statement explicitly mentions the order of the groups.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

[Here](http://oeis.org/A000001) is a list of the number of groups of order $n$ for $n=1,\ldots,2015$.  If you add up the number of groups of order other than $1024$, you get $423{,}164{,}062$.  There are $49{,}487{,}365{,}422$ groups of order $1024$, so you can see the assertion is true.  (In fact the percentage is about $99.15\%$.)

As far as I know there is no reasonable way to deduce *a priori* the number of isomorphism classes of groups of a given order, though I believe that combinatorial group theory has some methods for specific cases.  A general rule of thumb is that there are a *ton* of $2$-groups, and in fact I have heard it said that "almost all finite groups are $2$-groups" (though I cannot cite a reference for this statement).

---

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, "almost all finite groups are $2$-groups" is still a conjecture.  There is an asymptotic bound on the number of $p$-groups of order $p^n$, however.  Denoting by $\mu(p,n)$ the number of groups of order $p^n$, $$\mu(p,n)=p^{\left(\frac{2}{27}+O(n^{-1/3})\right)n^3},$$ which is proven [here](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s3-15/1/151.extract).  This colossal growth along with the results of [Besche, Eick & O'Brien](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.9.8357) seem to be what primarily motivated the conjecture.

Comment: A while ago I tried to find a reference for this "almost all..." result. I think it is just a folklore statement, with the paper which is the subject of this thread proffered as evidence.

Comment: (I wonder if there are more groups of order $3^{10}$ than of order $2^{10}$? Genericity proofs are...unsavoury...at least to my pallet...)

Comment: (...because a genericity result based on order would loose the fact that there are more groups of order $p^n$ than of $2>n$ purely because $2<p$...which doesn't quite ring true with reality...for some interpretation of reality...)

Comment: There are probably more groups of order $3^{10}$ than $2^{10}$, but what the conjecture means is that if you denote by $\mu(n)$ the number of groups of order less than or equal to $n$ and by $\rho(n)$ the number of $2$-groups of order less than or equal to $n$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\rho(n)/\mu(n)=1$.

Comment: Of course it's possible to deduce the number of isomorphism classes of groups of (finite) order $n$: write down all possible $n$ by $n$ multiplication tables, check which satisfy the group axioms, check every bijection between each pair to see if it's a group isomorphism. Since everything is finite, this can all be computed in finite time. The hard part is finding ways to do it in a *sane* amount of time.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: I know this, I am just saying that it is somewhat unsavoury. For example, one can do what you are saying and perhaps prove that almost all groups are two-groups, but then one can use exponents of $p$-groups and perhaps prove that "almost no" p-groups are $2$-groups (assuming there are more groups of order $p^n$ than of order $2^n$, $p>2$). If you change your definition of genericity you change your result...

Comment: According to the list linked in the answer, there are 504 groups of order $3^6=729$ and 267 groups of order $2^6=64$. There are 15 groups of order $5^4=625$ and also of order $3^4=81$ and 14 groups of order $2^4=16$.

Comment: Almost all groups are infinite.

Answer (score 31):

This is true. The amount of groups of order at most 2000 (up to isomorphism) was calculated precisely for the first time in 2001 by [Besche, Eick and O'Brien](http://www.aimsciences.org/journals/pdfsnews.jsp?paperID=2377&mode=full). Here is the announcement of their result:

> We announce the construction up to isomorphism of the $49 910 529 484$ groups of order at most $2000$.

In table 1 the number of groups of order $1024$ is given, it is $49 487 365 422$. Hence ~99.2% of all groups of order at most $2000$ have order $1024$.

**EDIT (2022):** See the other answer for a recent correction to the precise number.

Answer (score 11):

Burrell notices [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2021.2006680), that there is a mistake in the original calculation.
Actually a recent enumeration of groups of order $2^{10}$ shows, that there are
$$
49487367289
$$
groups of this order, and not $49487365422$. The data has been corrected recently also on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000001). Clearly this does not matter for the present question. Still more than $99\%$ of all groups of order $n\le 2000$ have order $1024$.