# Almost all finite groups have order $2^n$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

This might be a stupid question, but here it goes:

Is anything known about, whether:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\#\{\text{Groups of order }2^n\}}{\#\{\text{Groups of order} \leq 2^n\}} = 1$$

(where two groups are considered the same, if they are isomorphic).

Comment: Possible related (not the same): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456419, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241369

Comment: @Watson It is more than "possibly related". It says that the above question is still an open conjecture, and gives known asymptotics in this direction.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I wasn't sure, what exactly was meant by "almost all finite groups are $2$-groups".