# On high number of nonisomorphic groups of order $2^n$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Let $G(n)$ denote number of non isomorphic groups of  order $n$. So is $G(2^n)>G(m)$ for $m$ less than $2^n$ always? Ignore $2$.

Comment: Yes, almost all finite groups are $2$-groups. There are asymptotic formulas, i.e., the number of isomorphism classes of groups of order $p^n$ grows as $p^{\frac{2}{27}n^3 + O(n^{8/3})}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde is this actually known? It seems that surprisingly little is known about the growth for non prime powers.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft No, this is only a conjecture so far, you are right. There is of course the computation of all groups of order $n\le 2000$ by Bettina Eick et al., where $99\%$ of all groups have order $2^{10}$.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241369/more-than-99-of-groups-of-order-less-than-2000-are-of-order-1024/241381#241381), and [this duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836875/almost-all-finite-groups-have-order-2n?noredirect=1&lq=1) of it.