# How to classify $2^n$ groups up to isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Groups of order $2^n$ have most non-isomorphic types and are notoriously hard to classify. For example, order $32$ has $51$ non-isomorphic groups, and order $64$ has $267$ ones. In general group theory texts, only groups of order up to $15$ are (completely) classified. Even the order of $16$ is not available for a full classification.

On [this website](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/), all groups up to order $500$ are classified with given names. My question is, are groups of $64$ or $128$ or higher classified manually through presentations or by programming (computational group theory)?

Comment: It becomes extremely difficult. See this for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241369/more-than-99-of-groups-of-order-less-than-2000-are-of-order-1024 . The number of groups of order $2048$ is, as far as I know, still unknown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is known that the number of isomorphism classes of groups of order $p^n$ ($p$ prime) grows as $p^{{\frac{2}{27}n^3}
+O(n^{8/3})}$ (Charles Sims, *Enumerating p-groups*, Proc. London Math. Soc., Series 3, **15** (1965), 151-166).

Because of this exponential growth, is it believed that almost all finite groups are $2$-groups: the fraction of isomorphism classes of $2$-groups among isomorphism classes of groups of order at most $n$ is thought to tend to $1$ as $n$ tends to infinity. If you look at the table in [this paper](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/%7Eobrien/research/gnu.pdf) of Conway, Dietrich and O'Brien, you can see that of the 49 910 529 484 different groups of order at most $2000$, 49 487 367 289, or just over 99%, are the $2$-groups of order 1024.

The first to create some order in the plethora of groups of prime-power order was Philip Hall (*The classification of prime-power groups*, J. Reine Angew. Math. **182** (1940),130-141). He observed that the notion of *isomorphism* of groups is really too strong to give rise to a satisfactory classification and that it had to be replaced by a weaker equivalence relation. Subsequently he discovered a suitable equivalence relation
and called it *isoclinism* of groups. It is this classification principle that underlies the mentioned monograph of M. Hall and J. K. Senior on the classification of $2$-groups of order at most $64$ (see their first DEFINITION, where isoclinism class is not mentioned but rather *family*). Another strategy for classification is looking at coclasses: the *coclass* of a finite $p$-group of order $p^n$ and nilpotency class $c$ is $n−c$.

Yet another approach is that of Marcus du Sautoy (1999): he constructs certain zeta-functions and uses $p$-adic integrals to capture the number of finite $p$-groups, see this [paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/era/1999-05-16/S1079-6762-99-00069-4/S1079-6762-99-00069-4.pdf), or *Zeta functions of Groups: the Quest for Order versus the Flight from Ennui*, which appeared in Groups St Andrews 2001, LMS Lecture Note Series **304** (2001), 150-189.

Comment: Note that while $p^{{\frac{2}{27}n^3}+O(n^{8/3})}$ is (super)exponential in $n$, it is quasipolynomial in $p^n$, which is the order of the group and the more relevant quantity if you are going to be comparing to groups of arbitrary order.

Answer (score 7):

Order 64 was done by hand still -- Hall, Marshall, Jr.; Senior, James K.
The groups of order $2^n$ ($n\le 6$).
Macmillan, 1964. Order 128 is by computer, but would have been possible by hand, see also O'Brien, Vaughan-Lee The groups with order $p^7$ for odd prime $p$.
J. Algebra 292 (2005), 243–258