What means $p^{\frac{2}{27}n^{3}+O\left(n^{8/3}\right)}$?
$f(n)$ is the number of groups of order $n$ up to isomorphism.
I am reading this article. There is a section called "Great gnus". In this section, there is an asymptotic estimate of $f(n)$. $$p^{\frac{2}{27}n^{3}+O\left(n^{8/3}\right)}$$
What it means?
In my head it means that for every positive constant $k$
$$f(p^{n}) \leq p^{\frac{2}{27}n^{3}+k\cdot n^{8/3}}$$
for sufficient large $n$. Am I correct?

Isomorphism (not "isomorfism"). And see wikipedia for the big O notation.

No that is not correct. The answers below give the correct interpretation.

See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4872361/how-to-classify-2n-groups-up-to-isomorphism/4872730#4872730

Standard sense: there exists $g(n)$ such that asymptotic estimate of $f(n)$ is  $$p^{\frac{2}{27}n^{3} + g(n)}$$  and $g(n) = O\left(n^{8/3}\right)$.
Moreover, $g(n) =  O\left(n^{8/3}\right)$ iff $|g(n)| \le k n^{8/3}$ for some constant $k$.

Here is a possible interpretation:
$$
f(n) = a^{g(n)+O(h(n))} \; \Leftrightarrow \; \log_a f(n) - g(n) = O(h(n)) 
$$
as $ n \to \infty$.
This is equivalent to
$$
\exists \, C\, \forall \, n \, \frac{f(n)}{a^{g(n)}} \le C^{h(n)} \, .
$$
